# MySQL query to fetch all products and its category

Tags: mysql

I am trying to fetch products and include the associated categories as a comma separated list. Below is what I tried, but it returns only 1 product. I tried LEFT and LEFT OUTER joins but neither worked. Any ideas?

```
SELECT 'U' as ACTION
       , product_id
       , GROUP_CONCAT(PC.category_id SEPARATOR ', ') as Categories 
FROM   Products P LEFT JOIN Product_Category PC 
           ON PC.product_id = P.product_id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add group by

```
SELECT 'U' as ACTION, product_id, GROUP_CONCAT(PC.category_id SEPARATOR ', ')     as Categories 
FROM Products P LEFT JOIN Product_Category PC 
ON PC.product_id = P.product_id group by P.product_id;
```

-----------------example -----------

```
select * from calls;
+----+------------+---------+
| id | date       | user_id |
+----+------------+---------+
|  1 | 2016-06-22 |       1 |
|  2 | 2016-06-22 |    NULL |
|  3 | 2016-06-22 |    NULL |
|  4 | 2016-06-23 |       2 |
|  5 | 2016-06-23 |       1 |
|  6 | 2016-06-23 |       1 |
|  7 | 2016-06-23 |    NULL |
+----+------------+---------+
7 rows in set (0.03 sec)

mysql> select * from payments;
+----+------------+---------+-------+
| id | date       | user_id | value |
+----+------------+---------+-------+
|  1 | 2016-06-22 |       1 |    10 |
|  2 | 2016-06-22 |       3 |    15 |
|  3 | 2016-06-22 |       4 |    20 |
|  4 | 2016-06-23 |       2 |   100 |
|  5 | 2016-06-23 |       1 |   150 |
+----+------------+---------+-------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select c.user_id,group_concat(p.value) from calls c inner join payments p on p.user_id=c.user_id group by c.user_id;
+---------+-----------------------+
| user_id | group_concat(p.value) |
+---------+-----------------------+
|       1 | 10,150,10,150,10,150  |
|       2 | 100                   |
+---------+-----------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: yes did, it wont allow to mark answer before 5 minutes.. :)

Answer (score 1):

`GROUP_CONCAT` function is one aggregate functions, and is using `GROUP BY` clause. If you have no `GROUP BY` in your `SELECT` statement, then it uses all found results.